# How do I make a global Websocket ws in SvelteKit using Prisma

Tags: websocket, svelte, sveltekit, ws

I am a newer developer and I am trying to add a websocket, which I have never done, that will allow my Sveltekit app to update each client connected to the server. I have a websocket.js file in the root of the project which makes a request to an api endpoint every five seconds that queries the database using prisma.

```js
import WebSocket, { WebSocketServer } from 'ws';

const wss = new WebSocketServer({ noServer: true });

// When a client connects to the server
wss.on('connection', async (socket) => {
    try {
        // Fetch the most recent data from the database using a Prisma query
        const data = await fetch('api/data', {
            method: 'GET'
        });
        console.log('data from initial recieved')
        // Send the data to the client as a JSON string
        socket.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});

setInterval(async () => {
    try {
        // Fetch the updated data from the database using a Prisma query
        const data = await fetch('api/data', {
            method: 'GET'
        });
        console.log('data from update recieved')
        console.log(data)

        // Send the data to all connected clients as a JSON string
        wss.clients.forEach((client) => {
            if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                client.send(JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}, 5000);

export default wss;
```

In my page I am importing wss from websocket.js. I am getting the error "Cannot use relative URL (api/data) with global fetch — use `event.fetch`" I was originally putting my prisma database query in the websocket.js file instead of making an endpoint but I was getting an error. So I think that the websocket as it currently is is running on my client and not my server. I'm unsure how to make the websocket run on the server and query the database and push it to each client. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You might wanna try using SvelteKits own fetch function, which can make relative requests. See the documentation section "Making fetch requests": https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load